# What area of machine learning should I look into to automatically extract certain info from messages

Tags: nlp

I have an app that extracts information from incoming messages.  The messages all contain the same information, but they have different forms depending on the source that sent them.

Example:

Message from source A :

```
A: You spent $50.00 at Macy's on 2/20/12
```

Message from source B :

```
Purchase, $50.00, Macy's, 2Feb2012, Balance $5000.00
```

Every message from a single source has the same form though. So at the moment, I'm doing it by writing a set of regular expressions to first identify which message I'm trying to decode (i.e. what source it came from so I know what the form of the message is), and then extracting the necessary information from the message (in the above example, I want to know the transaction amount, the store where the transaction happened, and the date).  If I discover a new source for a message, or a source changes the format of their message (doesn't happen very often, but could happen), I need to manually write the regular expressions for that message. I'm sure however that I could automate this using some kind of machine learning technique.  I just don't know much about machine learning, and I don't know where to even start looking for a technique that would apply to my problem.  I would like someone to just point me in the right direction on where to start reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to detect and label amounts, dates, person names and similar information you can use a technique called Named Entity Recognition. The [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) comes with pretrained, ready to use models. 
You also use whatever labeled data you have generated so far to learn a custom model for your application. The standard techniques used for this purpose are Conditional Random Fields or Sequence Perceptron. There are many toolkits implementing these models, including:

- [Wapiti](http://wapiti.limsi.fr) - A simple and fast discriminative sequence labelling toolkit.
- [Sequor](http://code.google.com/p/sequor/) - sequence labeler based on Collins's (2002) perceptron.

Comment: The Stanford tools look useful.  It will take me some time to digest what's out there, but this has certainly pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!